# Simple HTML Dom and CURL error

Tags: php, curl

I have some problem here,

my code is:

```
<?php
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.website.org');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'name');
    $html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
    $element= $html->find("div[class=something]");
    echo $element;
?>
```

and I get this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object on line 10

Comment: `include_once("simple_html_dom.php");` what does this file do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a member function on a non-object. In this case you can't use the member function `find` on `$element` which is a `string`.

From the documentation of **[curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)**:

> Return Values
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

The result being the html content of the page you try to get which is a `STRING`

Try to use **[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)** and you will see by yourself.

So I guess you want to use the **[DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)** and the **[DOMXpath class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)** and do something like:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.website.org');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'name');
$html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$encodeHtml = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($html));
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($encodeHtml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$res = $xpath->query($Path);
```

`$Path` being the xpath of the element you are trying to echo.

Comment: @MasoudHB You're welcom, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

- Please try to understand the very basics of Object-Orientation.
- You'll have to instantiate a simple_html_dom object to call methods on it.
- Please replace `$html = curl_exec($curl_handle);` with
  `$result=curl_exec($curl_handle);
  $html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load($result);`

and move `include_once("simple_html_dom.php");` above this part.

Comment: $tillz thanks a lot for your short and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'name');
$html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$mytag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($mytag  as $value) {
    //echo $value->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    //echo  $value->getAttribute('class'), PHP_EOL;
    if($value->getAttribute('class') == "someclass"){
        //do something 
    }

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php